# Azure Bing Speech API and Speech to Text

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am confused by Bing Speech API(https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/services/cognitive-services/speech/) and Speech to Text(https://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/services/cognitive-services/speech-to-text/)

My questions are

1) Are Bing Speech API and Speech to Text different service?

2) Does Bing Speech API have like custom language model? If so, does it support Japanese?

3) Does custom language model of Speech to Text support Japanese?

4) Does Speech to Text have SDK for iOS?

Thanks